Install GDAL into conda environment
I have a conda environment and install gdal into it as suggested here https://gdal.org/api/python_bindings.html with the following command:
conda install -c conda-forge gdal

However, when I try to import the modul gdal with the command
from osgeo import gdal

I get the Error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_gdal'

What am I doing wrong, and how do I need to properly install gdal?
I'm using Linux Mint.

I tried it with conda install gdal  and only this seems to work.

Are the packages still installed from conda-forge? Check with conda list. conda install -c conda-forge gdal works for me on Windows. I have Miniconda v. 23.3.1. Python 3.12.3 got installed.

Yes, gdal is installed with conda-forge according to the list.

I think you can be happy then if you do not definitely want to know why the documented command did not work for you.

If you want to explore further on the conda-forge channel install, you can try: conda install -c conda-forge gdal krb5 to see if that solves the issue.

@user30184 I had a look into my list and I suspect that I use per default conda-forge, as it is described here: https://conda-forge.org/docs/user/introduction/
However, I didn't want to ask as then I would add another question to this question and I made the experience, that this forum is quite strict in this regard. Of course I would be happy to hear an explanation for it, but would not explicitly ask within this question.

When using conda it is in general a good idea to avoid mixing packages from different channels.
Anaconda and miniconda use defaults as default channel, so when you use conda install -c conda-forge gdal only gdal will be installed from the conda-forge channel and most other dependencies will be installed from defaults, possibly leading to incompatibilities.
So, when you want to install something explicitly from the conda-forge channel, it is a good idea to create a new environment and configure it so the highest priority is given to conda forge for everything being installed in this environment, like this:
conda create -n gdal_cf
conda activate gdal_cf
conda config --env --add channels conda-forge
conda config --env --set channel_priority strict
conda install gdal

This should avoid this kind of issues.
Reference: here.
Regarding conda install gdal working: this will work as well as it will install gdal as well as all dependencies from defaults. However, the latest version on defaults is 3.6.2, so it trails 3 feature versions as 3.9 is the latest version (which is available on conda-forge).

Notice also that if you happen to work for a bigger company (>200 people)  then the default conda channel is not free, while conda-forge is https://www.anaconda.com/blog/is-conda-free.

@user30184 This is indeed a very interesting fact. Didn't know that! Thank you for sharing!

Thank you @Pieter! Very helpful!
